# Web Service move list item to sub-folder with strict permissions

Tags: 2013, web-services

We want to use a workflow to move a list item to a subfolder in the same list based off employee type/selection from a dropdown column.

If the dropdown value selected is 'manager', then we want to move the list item to a subfolder called 'manager' with tighter permissions.

We're looking at this as an example, but I don't see how to take a single item and actually move it:

```
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/call-http-web-service-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-spd/
```

Our call is to:

```
http://oursite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Succession%20Management%20Form')/items([%Current Item:ID %])
```

What I'm missing his how to place this list item into a sub-folder.

We have a lookup field that uses this list's ID field that self-references for lookups + many specific content type fields that would copy over.  Seems like a web service is the way to go to pull all these fields over to that sub-folder.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the OOTB Content Organizer, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-Content-Organizer-to-route-documents-B0875658-69BC-4F48-ADDB-E3C5F01F2D9A.  Perhaps that could be an alternative?

Comment: Tried this route, but the lookup column goes to blank on the copy.

Comment: We're working on a workflow that moves the title, but the listdata.svc call via HTTP Post only allows us to pull over the Title to the sub-folder with tighter permissions.  Do I need to build the dictionary for every field for each of the available 3 content types on this list?  If I add any field into my RequestContent dictionary variable which has the Title and Path, I get an error:
{"error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Error processing request stream. The payload must represent a valid array format for collections."}}}